# if query to compare two lists in perl

Tags: perl, if-statement

I have 2 lists, one is a list of files and the other is a logfile.

I want the `if` query to print out every line of the logfile where a file from the list is named.
E.g.: list of files:

```
myfile1.txt
myfile2.txt
```

logfile:

```
line 1   html
line 2   filename="myfile2.txt"
line 3   /html
line 4   /xml
```

The desired output would be :

`myfile2.txt found at line 2`

I've tried several queries, such as

```
if(index($Lines_Logfile[$logcounter] ,'Lines_Name[$namecounter]') != -1);
```

or

```
if($Lines_Logfile[$logcounter] =~ m/$Lines_Name[$namecounter]/);
```

where `$Lines_Logfile` and `$Lines_Name` are the lists, and `$namecounter` and `$logcounter` are the lines of the `for` loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression.  The trick is recognizing that you need to use [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) or `\Q...\E` to escape regex special characters, and word boundaries `\b` to prevent matching a substring.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @files = qw(myfile1.txt myfile2.txt);

#open my $fh, '<', 'yourfile.log';   
my $fh = \*DATA;   # Testing data used for debug purposes

while (<$fh>) {
    for my $file (@files) {
        if (/\b\Q$file\E\b/) {
            print "$file found at line $.: $_";
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
html
filename="myfile2.txt"
/html
/xml
```

Outputs:

```
myfile2.txt found at line 2: filename="myfile2.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. The only problem is that it results in an extreme long runtime. Is there any Option beside using a Regex?